# Some code to edit thumbnail such as Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, thumbnails

I need some code to edit thumbnail such as Facebook-style.

I can drag an area of image to select thumbnail.

please give me some idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) is usually a pretty good solution for this, [you can check out the demos here](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php).

Specifically, you probably want the [thumbnail demo](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail) :)